# Limit of $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$ as n approaches infinity

Tags: limits

This is what I've done:

$$\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} = \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \exp(\log\left(\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\right) = \exp(n\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$$

And then I can take the limit like this:

$$\exp\left(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\right)$$

But where to from here?

Comment: Hint: what is the definition of $e$ ?

Comment: The limit of the *reciprocal* may be already familiar.

Comment: How about $\frac{lnn-ln(n+1)}{1/n}$ and use L'Hospital Rule?

Comment: @AndréNicolas. You are right but perhaps he has to prove the limit as an exercise...

Comment: As Andre' says, just divide numerator and denominator by $n^n$ and the limit in the reciprocal is familiar. Usually school courses require you to show it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without resorting to L'Hopital and using only the basic equalities,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \\
&= e,
\end{align*}
so the reciprocal tends to $1/e$.

Comment: Selecting this as best answer since the way I approached the problem was quite contrived, and this shows the simpler and better way to do it. As other commenters noted, the expression $\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$ simplifies to $\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{n})^n}$ and taking the limit of this gives $\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss your approach. It's a standard technique to turn $a^x$ into $e^{x \ln a}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\exp\left(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\right)$$
$$= \exp\left(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)$$
$$= \exp\left(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^2 + n}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}\right)$$
$$= \exp\left(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{-n^2}{n^2 + 1}\right)$$
$$= \exp(-1)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you accept that $e$ is the unique number such that $1 = ∫_1^e \frac{dt}{t}$, then there is a proof [here](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma122/elimit.pdf) of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n→ e$ which then gives by Nitin's argument the result.